# How to get object property dynamically using a custom function

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties, propertypath

I have a funciton that accept a property name

```
func(propertyName) {
  return object[propertyName];
}
```

so by calling `func('value')` will return the `object.value`

However the object is complex, so it has inner props

What I want to do is to be able to do that `func('property1.property2')`

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Comment: `let property = {name:'test'}
function test(prop) {
  console.log(prop)
}
test(property.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) ensures both a fail safe implementation and a fail safe access of any passed property key path at any passed type/object ...

```js
function getValueByKeyPath(obj, path) {
  return String(path)
    .split('.')
    .reduce((value, key) => value?.[key], Object(obj))
}

const sampleData = {
  foo: {
    value: 'foo',
    bar: {
      value: 'bar',
      baz: {
        value: 'baz',
      },
    },
  },
};

console.log(
  "getValueByKeyPath(sampleData, 'foo.bar.baz') ...",
  getValueByKeyPath(sampleData, 'foo.bar.baz')
);
console.log(
  "getValueByKeyPath(sampleData, 'foo.bar.baz.value') ...",
  getValueByKeyPath(sampleData, 'foo.bar.baz.value')
);

console.log(
  "\nfail safe ... getValueByKeyPath(sampleData, 'foo.biz.baz.value') ...",
  getValueByKeyPath(sampleData, 'foo.biz.baz.value')
);

console.log(
  "\nfail safe ... getValueByKeyPath('', 'toString') ...",
  getValueByKeyPath('', 'toString')
);
console.log(
  "fail safe ... getValueByKeyPath(null, '') ...",
  getValueByKeyPath(null, '')
);
console.log(
  "fail safe ... getValueByKeyPath() ...",
  getValueByKeyPath()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The above approach can be extended to bracket notation with both quoted and unquoted keys for e.g. nested/mixed object and array based data-structures. Then one does not split the key-path at simply any dot but also at any opening and closing bracket while capturing the value inside the brackets. The result of this split operation needs to be sanitized from some falsy artifacts, the reducing part stays the same ...

```js
function getValueByKeyPath(obj, path) {
  return String(path)
    .split(/\.|\[['"]?([^'"\]]*)['"]?\]/)
    .filter(elm => !!elm)
    .reduce((value, key) => value?.[key], Object(obj))
}

const sampleDataA = {
  foo: {
    value: 'foo',
    bar: {
      value: 'bar',
      baz: {
        value: 'baz',
      },
    },
  },
};
const sampleDataB = {
  foo: {
    bar: [{
      baz: {
        value: 'baz',
        biz: {
          value: 'biz',
        },
      }
    }, {
      buzz: {
        value: 'buzz',
        booz: {
          value: 'booz',
        },
      }
    }],
  },
};

console.log(
  "getValueByKeyPath(sampleDataA, 'foo.bar.baz.value') ...",
  getValueByKeyPath(sampleDataA, 'foo.bar.baz.value')
);
console.log(
  "getValueByKeyPath(sampleDataA, 'foo.bar[\"baz\"].value') ...",
  getValueByKeyPath(sampleDataA, 'foo.bar["baz"].value')
);
console.log(
  "getValueByKeyPath(sampleDataB, 'foo.bar[1][\"buzz\"].booz') ...",
  getValueByKeyPath(sampleDataB, 'foo.bar[1]["buzz"].booz')
);
console.log(
  "fail safe ... getValueByKeyPath(sampleDataB, 'foo.bar[2].buzz.booz') ...",
  getValueByKeyPath(sampleDataB, 'foo.bar[2].buzz.booz')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: btw [the highest rated and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path#answer-6491621) of the above posted duplicate link fails if one invokes it like `Object.byString(sampleDataB, 'foo.bar[1]["buzz"].booz');` whereas it does work for `Object.byString(sampleDataB, 'foo.bar[1].buzz.booz')`. Thus the provided implementation of `Object.byString` is not reliable if it comes to a proper handling of bracket notation with quoted strings.

Comment: I like this one from the same thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/41326547/2926340

Comment: @sreginogemoh ... well, the basic idea behind both approaches is the same. Both approaches too, focus on handling unreliable arguments and on how to exit the iteration with a ready consumed object. Yet I would say the 3 commands (chained operations) of `.split().filter().reduce()` are more expressive/readable than the linked approach with its `for` loop and the handling of `continue` and the multiple `return`s.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

example data:
`a={b:{c:"hellooo"}};`

function:
`function getValue(object,propertyName){ return propertyName.split(".").reduce((a,c)=>a[c],object); }`

response:

`getValue(a,"b.c") = hellooo`